# Unable to remove SQLite Database file

Tags: ios, swift2

I am new to Xcode and ios. I am using Xcode 7.3 version and swift2.2

I have removed a per-populated SQlite Db from my project. Later, I used Add file menu in Xcode to add the same name SQLite Db with only modified the content of the field.  Example , fieldname :addr ,  the content :123, 5th ave  , now the same filedname :addr   ,the content :12, Broadway

After added the modified content SQLite DB, the code STILL using the old content that is 123,5th ave!

```
let querySQL = "select Sid, location, Addr from tblPlaces where Sid ="  + myId

 let result: FMResultSet? = MyDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsinArray:nil)

 if result?.next() == true {

   let strAddr = results!stringForColumn("Addr")

 }else {

 }

I have created a class to handle the creation of SQLite DB in AppDelegate:

  Util.copyFile("SqliteDB filename")


here the code:
class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {

        var dbPath: NSString = getPath(fileName)

        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {

           let documentsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL
           let fromPath = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(filename as string)

           var error : NSError?

          do {
              try filemanager.CopyItemAtPath(fromPath.path!, toPath: dbPath)

           }catch let error1 as NSError {

          error = error1
        }

    }



// GetPath of the SQLite file

class func getPath(filename : String) -> string {

  let documentDirectory = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory,inDomain:
    UserDomainMask, appropriateURLURL:nil, create: true)

 return documentDirectory.URLbyAppendingPathComponent(filename).path! 

}
```

What this happened? How to do the right way?

If I remove the SQlite Db file say MyDB.sqlite, and later I add in the same name Db file with content modified, I should get the new content. But this is not the case.

Comment: The usual process is to copy the sqlite file from your bundle to a local folder.  Is it possible that copy failed because of the existing file?

Comment: I don't get u. Say  my Project name Show in Xcode is MyPlaces, I add pre-populated SQLite file in this folder thru xcode. To delete, I just right click the SQLite file and delete. Before adding,  I have added libsqlite3.dylib in the build setting. The code still run but still getting the old data!

Comment: Please see below.  Basically, while in your app's bundle, the sqlite file is read only.  You need to make a copy in your documents folder.  I've provided some Obj c code that does this but I don't know if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your file in the application bundle, i.e., to be distributed with your app.  That file is read only.  To update the file (including scheme restructuring) you would need to copy the the file to your documents folder, and update it there.  Otherwise, your update will fail, leaving you with the same file as before.

I think this is what is happening.

For distribution it is also necessary that any such file be flagged NOT to backup to icloud or the app is rejected.

I use the following method (sorry, obj c) to copy the file from the bundle to the documents directory (sorry this code is sloppy but it may convey the basic idea).

```
+ (void)copyBundleFileToStoresDirectory:(NSString *)filename


{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:nil]];
    NSURL *pathURL = [SVOFileSystemMethods documentsSubdirectory:@"Stores" skipBackup:YES];

    if (fileURL)
    {
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:fileURL toURL:pathURL error:&error])
        {
        //           NSLog(@"File successfully copied");
        }
        else
        {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"error", nil) message: NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to copy database from bundle.", nil)
                                  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            NSLog(@"Error description-%@ \n", [error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"Error reason-%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
        }
}
```

}

```
// //  flags URL to exclude from backup //
+ (BOOL) addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }

    return success; }
```

Comment: I just edited my post. I use the CopyFile function to copy the Sqlite db file into required directory. But I still get the old content even I have modified or changed the content. thanks

Comment: This is what  I wanted to do. Replace the pre-populated Sqlite Db with another sqlite Db with everything the same except the content. What I need to do?

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't clear to me.  If you don't want the data in the sqlite database, why distribute it at all?  Just create it when the app first runs.

But any change to the sqlite file(s) you distribute must be made outside the bundle, that is, the file has to be copied to the user directories before you can update it.  But you cannot modify the bundle from your app.  

I feel like if you provide a little more information on what/why you're trying to do this it would be useful.

Comment: This is the scenario: I add a pre-populated with data Sqlite Db, say MyPlacesDB, into my project. I used the copyFile function in my above post to copy MyPlacesDB in AppDelegate. This will copy MyPlacesDB from Bundle into Document Directory in iphone order to work. I discovered the data from MyPlacesDB is not accurate, so I deleted it from the Project. I made changes in content in another copy with same name MyPlacesDB using SQliteBrowser . Later, I add this modified MPlacesDB into Project and run. I GET the same old data but not the changes I made.So,I wanted to know why this happen. Thanks